# An interpolation inequality.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, real-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

For all $s>0$ define for $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ the function:
\begin{equation}
g(\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+k)^s(\sqrt{1-\epsilon})^k.
\end{equation}
Prove that $\exists C>0$ and $\phi(s)$ such that:
\begin{equation}
g(\epsilon)\leq C \epsilon^{\phi(s)}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Where does this arise? What makes you think this is true?

Comment: A professor gave us this exercise, but my colleagues and I weren't able to solve it, even if we found it very interesting.

Comment: So why not ask this professor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
g(\epsilon)=\sum_{k\ge 1} k^se^{\frac {k-1}2\ln(1-\epsilon)}
\lesssim \int_0^{+\infty} x^s e^{-a\epsilon x} dx=
 \int_0^{+\infty}x^s e^{-ax}dx\epsilon^{-s-1}
$$
where $a$ is a fixed constant. So
$$
C=\int_0^{+\infty}x^s e^{-ax}dx,\quad \phi(s)=-s-1.
$$

Comment: I think that the constant $a$ depends on $\epsilon$. I would like to find an estimate such that the constant $C$ doesn't depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Anyway I have some difficulty understanding your inequalities. For example:
\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{x-1}{2}ln(1-\epsilon)}\leq e^{-a\epsilon x}.
\end{equation}
Is that inequality true for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: $\epsilon \rightarrow 1$, sorry.

Comment: The only problem is when $\epsilon$ is small, and you do have a singularity at $\epsilon=0$.
Now for $x>1,0<\epsilon<1/4$,
$$
\frac{x-1}{2}\ln(1-\epsilon)\le\frac{x(-\epsilon/2)}{2}
$$
so you can take $a=1/4$. The bounded values of $x$ are unimportant.